# HTML not generated when DOM element is built inside a javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am retrieving a URL parameter with JavaScript that I pass to PHP using AJAX to query a database that returns a string.

On AJAX success, I use a function that calls another function where with a for loop I generate my HTML strings that I push to an array.

Then I assign it to the DOM elements innerHTML property but no HTML is being generated.

I tried a console.log inside the function to see if I actually get the string from the database, which I do.

[image: This is the console log output]

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src=http://localhost:81/jquery-3.6.0.min.js></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:81/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
</div>
<script type="application/javascript">
function query_string(variable)
{
   var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
   var vars = query.split("&");
   for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
           var pair = vars[i].split("=");
           if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
   }
   return(false);
}
//Getting the parameter-
v = query_string('v');
console.log(v);

//////////////////////////////////////////
var transcript_from_db = {};

function getTranscript(){
    $.ajax(
    {
        type:       "POST",
        dataType:   "text",
        url:        "query2.php",
        data:       "v="+v,
        success:    function(response){
                        transcript_from_db = response;
                        onAjaxSuccess();
                    },

    }
);
};
getTranscript();
function onAjaxSuccess(){
    var thestring = transcript_from_db;
    console.log(thestring);
    var chats=[];
 for (var chat in thestring.data){
  var str='';
  thestring.data[chat].forEach(ch=>str+='<div class="msg"><div class="'+ch.type+'"><div class="txt"><span class="name">'+ch.pop_name+'</span><span class="timestamp">'+ch.timestamp+'</span><span class="message">'+ch.msg+'</span></div></div></div>')
  chats.push(str)
 }
 document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0].innerHTML=chats.join('<div>');
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If I assign a test string to a variable outside a function and also do the for loop outside a function it works fine.

Like this:

```
thestring = {
  data: {
    chat: [{
  msg: "Hello there",
  pop_name: "Customer",
  timestamp: "17:05 PM",
  type: "bubble"
}, {
  msg: "Hi John! How can I help you?",
  pop_name: "Dialogflow",
  timestamp: "17:05 PM",
  type: "bubble alt"
}, {
  msg: "My dishwasher is broken!",
  pop_name: "Customer",
  timestamp: "17:06 PM",
  type: "bubble"
}, {
  msg: "Sorry to hear that but maybe I can help you!",
  pop_name: "Dialogflow",
  timestamp: "17:06 PM",
  type: "bubble alt"
}, {
  msg: "Can you tell me what model number is your diswhaser?",
  pop_name: "Dialogflow",
  timestamp: "17:06 PM",
  type: "bubble alt"
}]
  }
}  
var chats=[];
 for (var chat in thestring.data){
  var str='';
  thestring.data[chat].forEach(ch=>str+='<div class="msg"><div class="'+ch.type+'"><div class="txt"><span class="name">'+ch.pop_name+'</span><span class="timestamp">'+ch.timestamp+'</span><span class="message">'+ch.msg+'</span></div></div></div>')
  chats.push(str)
  console.log(chats);
 }
 document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0].innerHTML=chats.join('<div>');
```

This is the result of that:

[image: Output when outside function]

Comment: You call it "string", talk about a "string", set `dataType` to "text", but expect an object, and treat it as such. What's happening here?

Comment: `chats.join('<div>')` injects an unclosed `<div>` between those messages. Of course browser will close it somehow but you're asking for unexpected behaviours

Comment: `thestring = {}` here  in your test you are assigning it to an object, not a string. Are you sure your response is a JS object like this instead of a string?

Comment: @T J  The string returned from the database is exactly like in my text example that I assign to the thestring object. I tried to prove that by also writing it out to console.

Comment: You have `dataType:   "text"` ?

Comment: An object is saved to a DB without being serialized to a JSON and I think my problem now is that I now end up with a typeof string not object, and my for loop is not working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally saved the object as a valid JSON string in the database and then, once retrieved, I used JSON parse to assign it to an object.

This fixed the problem.